# Accessing Firestore Document data within JavaScript https on request function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a piece of my app where I need to make a call to a Firebase Function, which parses through Firestore data to return a dictionary that I will use to populate UI in Swift.

My function is declared as so:
`exports.getUIBetData = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {`

This function takes in a userID as body parameter. Then, I need to hit firebase to get a specific document's data tied to this userId and perform some actions on it. I believe I am running into some issues with the async functionality behind getting data from a document, as I keep getting errors or simple promises that haven't been resolved. Here is my query:

```
const body = request.body;
const userId = body.data.userId;
  const bettorIdDoc = admin.firestore()
      .collection("user_dim").doc(userId).get().data();
```

I can confirm that "user_dim" is a valid collection, and the userId is a key to a document within it. However, I can't access the fields tied to this doc.

I was originally trying with just .data(), and realized from the official documentation that you need to do .get().data(), however this is async. How do I handle the async nature when I am attempting to do this within my main function (`exports.getUIBetData = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {`)?

Error:
`TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).doc(...).get(...).data is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading data from Firestore (and pretty much any cloud API) is an asynchronous  operation. You can see this by checking the return type of `get()`, which is `Promise<DocumentSnapshot>` and not just `DocumentSnapshot`.

This means you'll have to use `then` or `await` (if you're in an `async` context) to be able call `data()`:

```
const bettorIdRef = admin.firestore()
   .collection("user_dim").doc(userId)
ref.get().then((snapshot) => console.log(snapshot.data());
```

Comment: The function getUIBetData is making requests and doing work in the back-end on querying Firestore and aggregating. It's called as so: ```exports.getUIBetData = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {
    
    const jsonBody = request.body;
    const userId = jsonBody.data.userId;
    getUIData(userId).then( success => {
        console.log(">>> on success");
        console.log(success);
    })
    
    return response.status(200).end();
})
;``` The query seems to execute all the way through and never finish or log anything in the [then] part. Why? I'm handling the above

Comment: It's hard to see here, but as far as I can tell it's the same problem: your `return response.status(200).end();` runs before the asynchronous data has loaded, and that aborts the function.